# Unity Movement - Okay, so I am trying to build a simple script for elevator movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, keyboard-events

The issue is I can only move upwards if the user holds the E key. Is there a way to have the user press the E key then just have the lift start?

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class liftScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public int speed = 1;
    private int i = 10;


    void OnTriggerStay()
    {
        startLift ();
    }

    void startLift()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E)) {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, 10, transform.position.z), Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can modify your code

```
public class liftScript : MonoBehaviour {

public int speed = 1;
private int i = 10;
bool keyPressed = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E)) {
        keyPressed = true;
    }

    if (keyPressed == true)
    {
        startLift();
    }

}

void startLift()
{
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (transform.position.x, 10, transform.position.z), Time.deltaTime * speed);
}

void stopLift()
{
    keyPressed = false;
}
}
```

Hope it can help you